# When I changing the background of wrapper, is not changing why?

Tags: css, wordpress, wrapper

When I changing the background of wrapper, is not changing, but when I changing the border,he is changing. I want my wrapper(content) to be transparent. I am using responsive theme in wordpress. This is my code:

```
#wrapper {
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    background:transparent;
    border: 4px solid #fffffff;
    border-radius: 1px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 40px auto 40px auto;
    padding: 0 20px 20px 20px;
    position: relative;
```

Comment: where to find html for wrapper. I am new here, and I don't now very mach :)

Comment: Please install Firebug on Firefox and press F12 key on your keyboard. You'd see the HTML or atleast right click and view source and put your HTML code here. We'd like to look into it.

Comment: We don't have enough information to be able to offer constructive options. If you set the background to transparent it will show the background of the parent element (or body) beneath it.

Comment: is this the html code: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="wp-toolbar" lang="en-US" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

Comment: <head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
<title>Edit Themes ‹ ecaroot's Blog! — WordPress</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
<link media="all" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=1&dir=ltr&load=admin-bar,wp-admin,buttons,wp-auth-check&ver=3.6.1" rel="stylesheet">
<link id="colors-css" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/css/colors-fresh.min.css?ver=3.6.1" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: <link id="thickbox-css" media="all" type="text/css" href="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-includes/js/thickbox/thickbox.css?ver=20121105" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=1&load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils&ver=3.6.1" type="text/javascript">
<style type="text/css">
<style media="print" type="text/css">
</head>
<body class="wp-admin wp-core-ui js theme-editor-php auto-fold admin-bar branch-3-6 version-3-6-1 admin-color-fresh locale-en-us customize-support">
</html>

Answer (score 2):

Change background to:

```
background-color:transparent;
```